# Function __init__ in python doesn't work

Tags: python

i have this python code:

```
class Tuna:
    def __Init__(self):
        print('birdie')

    def swim(self):
        print('swiminng')


tuntun = Tuna()
tuntun.swim()
```

which prints out:

```
swiminng
```

why is the **init** not working?

Comment: Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: `__init__` and `__Init__` would  be two different functions, and Python doesn't make any implicit use of `__Init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` is the initializer method.  `__Init__` is not.  If you don't override the `__init__` method by creating your own, the default one will be used (which does nothing after creating your instance).

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions. The OP, on several occasions (including the title), talks of `init`.

Comment: @roganjosh Why not?  They have a misunderstanding that needs clarification.

Comment: There is no misunderstanding, the title of the question uses the correct method name. Typos are off-topic, which is why it's a specific reason to close questions

Comment: @roganjosh You're making that assumption.  For all we know, this is a new programmer that doesn't realize Python is case sensitive.

Comment: I m indeed a new programmer that doesn't know Python is case sensitive. i didn't realize that the title and the content of the question were in different capitalization. thank you @touchmyboomboom

Comment: pls upvote my question